# Ember js and custom input attributes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, custom-attributes

I am just getting started with Ember, I am having a tough time trying to figure out how to add custom attributes to Ember's TextField to create an input. Through Questions answered on Stack Overflow I have no problem to insert custom data attributes that look like so

```
<input type="text" data-something="something"/>
```

But what I need is ...

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech speech enabled data-something="something"/>
```

Furthermore It would be awesome to make this a reusable component with jQuery UI's autocomplete plugin.

Template code I have so far...

```
//template file
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/auto-complete">
    {{input type="text" placeholder="Search Something"  class="search smallsearch" }}
</script>
```

I have figured out how to implement x-webkit-speech in this case.

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-something', 'x-webkit-speech']
});
```

And in my template,

```
{{input value=something type="text" data-something="something" x-webkit-speech="speech"}}
```

This seems to work nicely. I would still like to figure out how to use this as a component with jQuery UI Autocomplete. It would be awesome to pass in some datasource identifiers to it, and search the server for content.

Comment: Not sure what your question is...  Not a good form for StackOverflow.  You should boil it down to some specific questions about what you already tried, what you expected and what actually happened.